# Winforms WebBrowser control NewWindow3 event displays new browser with document mode 5

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, popup, webbrowser-control, new-window

I've got web pages embeded into win forms app. For my purposes I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13598/Extended-NET-2-0-WebBrowser-Control) web control. When new instance of browser is going to create, I handle NewWindow3 event and create new form with separate web browser control and pass it as ppDisp parameter. The problem I faced is that browser which is created from NewWindow3 event has document mode 5, lowest of all IE engines that I have on my machine. Can't understand why it's so and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had exactly the same problem with the TEmbeddedWB component (extended version of the TWebbrowser VCL component) in Delphi 5 for a long time.
I already did a lot of research in the past with no result. But today I found the solution after about 3 hours researching and trial&error. TEmbeddedWB has a public procedure "AssignEmptyDocument" with the following simple implementation:

```
procedure TEmbeddedWB.AssignEmptyDocument(bWait: Boolean = False);
begin
  Navigate('about:blank');
  if bWait then
    Wait;
end;
```

I have to execute this procedure BEFORE I assign the ppDisp. Here is my simplified solution in Delphi/Object pascal:

```
procedure Tfrm_browser.EmbeddedWBNewWindow3(ASender: TObject; var ppDisp: IDispatch;
  var Cancel: WordBool; dwFlags: Cardinal; const bstrUrlContext,
  bstrUrl: WideString);
var popup: Tfrm_popup;
begin   
  Application.CreateForm(Tfrm_popup, popup);
  popup.EmbeddedWB.AssignEmptyDocument;
  ppDisp := popup.EmbeddedWB.Application;
end;
```

In my case the documentMode of the popup is "9" afterwards, as expected.
So, simply try to do a "Navigate('about:blank');" before assigning the ppDisp. In my case it works like a charm.

The reason for this behavior I don't know, sorry...